# What is this texture called and how do I replicate it

Tags: ceiling, texture

I extended a ceiling about 13 inches and need to continue the same or similar pattern, only about 4 inches of it will be visible because I will be mounting wall cabinets below the new ceiling.

[image]

Comment: I don't really see a pattern it looks like a heavy application of mud then possibly a wet sponge to make the "pattern".

Comment: I guess the question is how do I repliacte this random look?  Sponge and joint compound? No sand, water?

Comment: With a wide mud knife or blade bring the new area to a similar thickness and let dry. After dry use a wet sponge with a light coating of fresh mud and drag in similar motions to make the ridges. From the photo I think this is how it was done.

Comment: I'm surprised at the confusion by others. It's stucco and I've seen this "pattern", if you will, on a number of buildings, particularly apartments including one I lived in back in the 1970s.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen this method, but to pick apart the various details I see in the picture, is a coat of drywall mud perhaps covering the whole wall first, let dry, then a tinner coat of mud applied with a wide bristle brush, perhaps a whitewash brush, then while it is still wet, "knocked down" with a wide spackle knife or trowel.